# Can I initialize references in a class? (perhaps in the constructor?)

Tags: c++, unit-testing, reference, googletest

I am a bit rusty on my C++, and in particular with *references*.

I have an old code, something like

```
TEST(SomeTest,someFunction){

AClass anObject= GetSomeObject();
ASingletonClass &aReference= ASingletonClass::GetInstance();
//... some more code
}
```

For reasons of design I have to rewrite this code, and this time I have to use an auxiliary class (*)

```
class ASingletonClassFixture: public testing:Test{
 public:
  void SetUp() override
   {
     anObject=GetSomeObject();
     aReference=  ASingletonClass::GetInstance();
   }

 protected:
  AClass  anObject;
  ASingletonClass   &aReference;  //<--I don't think this is correct
}
```

I think that the above code is not correct because references should be initialized when created.

So my question is how can I do something like this?  Can I do it in the constructor?

(*) The reason if you are interested -although not essential to know- is because I am writing a test fixture.

Comment: Yes you can do it in a constructor, if you use an *initialiser list*.

Comment: @john Ok, thanks. For simple values I can get it, but can I put the singleton `GetInstance` there too? How?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do it in the test constructor - and it is even the recommended way:

```
class ASingletonClassFixture: public testing::Test{
 public:
    ASingletonClassFixture() : aReference{ASingletonClass::GetInstance()} {}

  void SetUp() override
   {
     anObject=GetSomeObject();
   }

 protected:
  AClass  anObject;
  ASingletonClass   &aReference;  //<--I don't think this is correct
};
```

see [this FAQ](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/faq.md#should-i-use-the-constructordestructor-of-the-test-fixture-or-setupteardown-ctorvssetup).

However, be mindful that even though constructor and SetUp are called before ***each*** test body (the order is always ctor, SetUp, test body, TearDown, dtor), given you're using a singleton - it will be initialized only once and it's state will be shared between the test cases! What is more, if you have more test suites in the same test binary, as the singleton is most probably implemented as a static object, it will be initialized once for the whole test binary and deinitialized once the `main` method of the binary exits.

Comment: Thanks. I suppose that in the code, the initialization in `SetUp` is not needed anymore right?